# How to disable security (username/password) on Elasticsearch Docker container?

Tags: docker, security, elasticsearch, passwords

I would like to run the Dockerized version of [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) without username/password based security (I use other means, like AWS security groups).

How do I disable username/password security in Elasticsearch Docker?

Answer (score 43):

## Docker

Simply add the [`xpack.security.enabled=false` env var](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-do-i-disable-x-pack-security-on-the-elasticsearch-5-2-2-docker-image/78183):

```
docker run \
       -p 9200:9200 \
       -p 9300:9300 \
       -e "discovery.type=single-node" \
       -e "xpack.security.enabled=false" \
       docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.3
```

## Ansible

When running the container using [Ansible's docker_container](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/docker_container_module.html), some yaml idiosyncrasies forces you to use `0` instead of `false`:

```
env:
  discovery.type: "single-node"
  xpack.security.enabled: 0
  ..
```

Comment: are you sure setting it to 0 works? I get an exception that it must be a string.

Comment: false worked for me.

Comment: In my docker-compose, in `environment` section I had to put `"false"` as a string; `false` resulted in a build error (`services.storage.environment.xpack.security.enabled contains false, which is an invalid type, it should be a string, number, or a null`), and `0` resulted in a runtime error (`java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to load plugin class [org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.Security`).

Answer (score 0):

Remember to set this  env, to run ElasticSearch in non-production mode

```
       -e "discovery.type=single-node" \
```